# Timeout stopped working for me with Duktape v2.7.0

Tags: duktape

I had timeouts working nicely with Duktape v2.5.0.
In my duktape.h file, I appended:

`#define DUK_USE_EXEC_TIMEOUT_CHECK JSduk_timeout_check // our timeout check function`
`duk_bool_t JSduk_timeout_check(void *udata);`

and in the function do the checking of time and return 1 if the time has been exceeded, else 0.
It was working fine.

I have discovered that since updating to Duktape v2.7.0 it is no longer working.
I have remembered to append the same two lines to the duktape.h file.
But the function never gets called.

What am I missing, please?

MacOS Ventura M2 processor

I have put a trace in the function and also set a breakpoint using Xcode but it definitely is not being called.
The is no problem compiling and linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem... I had forgotten to set

```
#define DUK_USE_INTERRUPT_COUNTER
```

which I had previously in the duk_config.h file and which I overlooked updating.

I have now inserted this `#define` along with the other stuff in the duktape.h file, where it should not be overlooked.